# Re-enable route cache

Tags: networking, routing

In my kernel log I found:

```
lo: 5 rebuilds is over limit, route caching disabled
```

I know what triggers route cache rebuilds (too long hash bucket chains), but what exactly gets disabled? Which device? How can I check if it is still disabled? How can I re-enable it?

After this strange message I started having problems with other network devices like this:

```
unregister_netdevice: waiting for TUNNEL_03 to become free. Usage count = 2
```

And routing cache seems to be guilty here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into kernel sources I worked it out.

You have to increase your `net.ipv4.rt_cache_rebuild_count` and it works again.